# Why is my program printing some of the arrays under 5 and over 15.5 and not all of them?

Tags: arrays, for-loop

```
double[] prices = {20, 14.99, 3, 7.99, 2.34, 50, 1.49, 1.49, 8.99, 1.39, 50.00, 18.54, 12, 15.66, 6.77, 6.89, 13.67, 30, 40, 35.99};
double sum = 0;
int under5 = 0, over15= 0;
double[] under5list;
double[] over15list;
int c = 0;

//sum
for(int i = 0; i < prices.length; i++)
{
    sum += prices[i];
}
System.out.println("Sum of prices: " + sum);

//under 5 over 15.5
for(int i = 0; i < prices.length; i++)
{
    if(prices[i] < 5.0)
    {
        under5++;
    }
    else if(prices[i] > 15.5)
    {
        over15++;
    }
}

under5list = new double[under5];
over15list = new double[over15];

for(int i = 0; i < prices.length; i++)
{
    if(prices[i] < 5.0)
    {
        under5list[c] = prices[i];
        c++;
    }
    if(prices[i] > 15.5)
    {
        c = 0;
        over15list[c] = prices[i];
        c++;
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < under5list.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Under 5 prices:= " + under5list[i]);
}
for(int i = 0; i < over15list.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Over 15.5 prices:= " + over15list[i]);
}
```

Comment: This looks like Java. If you want anyone to see this question so that you can get an answer, you should add a language tag. Edit your post, please.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like when c is set to 0 in the for loop, then next match for over or under will be placed at the beginning of the corresponding under-array or  over-array.

You either need separate counters for indexing under5list and over15 list, or separate loops.